# Displaying data from an Intent in a fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have an activity that receives intents and then should display contents of the intents in a nested fragment. My code is the same as the Implement Effective Navigation tutorial which is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html) with a few modifications detailed below

As in the example the fragments are nested in the main activity with

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    ....
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
    ...
    public void updateFragUI() {

        if(rootView!=null){
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.example)).setText(mData.getSomething());                 
     }
```

I am having difficulties getting an instance of a fragment so that I can update the UI after the MainActivity receives an intent. The code to receive the intent and update the fragment is

```
    public class uiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mData = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ExampleService.EXAMPLE_INTENT);
        updateUI(mData);
    }
}



public void updateUI() {
        DummySectionFragment dummyFrag = (DummySectionFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(dummyFragId);

    if(dummyFrag==null) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Dummy frag is null");
    } else {
        if(dummyFrag.isVisible()) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Dummy frag is visable ");
                            dummyFrag.updateFragUI();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG,"Dummy frag is not visable");
        }
    }

    }
```

I have tried a number of approaches playing with the variable `dummyFragId` but I always find `dummyFrag` is always null. So far I've tried:

1. Experimenting with tags and ids in the XML code for the fragment. i.e. `dummFragId` is written as `R.id.dummy_fragment_id` (or Tag) with a corresponding property in `<FrameLayout ...`
2. Getting the fragment tag from the fragment transaction, but this is not done explicitly  in the effective navigation code i.e.
3. getting the fragment id using `dummyFragId = dummySectionFragment.getId()` i.e.

   ```
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int i) {
       switch (i) {
           case 0:
               // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
               // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
               return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

           case 1:
               Fragment dummySectionFragment = new DummySectionFragment();
               Bundle args = new Bundle();
               args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
               dummySectionFragment.setArguments(args);
               return dummySectionFragment;
   ```
4. Registering a receiver in the fragment. (The receiver is an external class that I cannot update the UI from)

I am open minded to the solution, I just want to know the best way of displaying information from an intent in a fragment.

Comment: I imagine the missing type here `public void updateUI(mData)` is an error in the post?

Comment: Also, what's `dummyFragId`? Did you define that somewhere to be `R.id.yourFragId`?

Comment: Hi @BobbyDigital, you're correct I have removed `mData` from the `updateUI` method. I left `dummyFragId` as a variable to illustrate one of my preious attempts at a solution, but have clarified it's use in the post. Any help is greatly apprepiated: I've spent two days on this problem so far!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a good solution by creating a register method in the fragment. There is no relevant code in the activity, it's all in the fragment. Hope this helps someone.

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public void updateFragUI() {
        Log.v(TAG, "updateFragUI received");
        ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.example_field))
                .setText(Double.toString(mData.getSomething()));
    }


    private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
            TransmittingService.STATE_UPDATE);

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mData = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(TransmittingService.STATE_VALUES);
            updateFragUI();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v(TAG, "registering Receiver");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG, "unregistering receiver");
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
...
}
```